# How to set permission for document library to enable file-> new option only in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, user-permissions

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

I need to enable new option only for user. other option need to disable in document library.

below is my screen shots for your reference.

[image]

I need to enable new option only for user. other option like Open&Check out, Manage, share&Track, copies, workflows, tags & notes need to disable also Library.

how to set and what permission need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your requirements can be achieved with a custom permission level.  If you create a new permission level and grant the user only Add Items, View Items (required), View Pages and Open access, they will only be able to upload and view items.

However, this will not stop them from opening items already uploaded.  The permission level requires they have the access to open if you want them to upload.

The only other way I can think of to accomplish your request is to create a file upload web part that will run with elevated privledges, allowing the user to upload a document even if they do not have access to the library.

Comment: Another option is to add some custom javascript in the backend of the list that disables the buttons on the ribbon.  An example of adding the code to a list can be found here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c98b1b05-9568-4a08-9de5-1239be44ec76/hide-sharepoint-ribbon-button-but-in-list-tab?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious 
Note, this will not affect ListViewWebparts.